# How can I create Swagger docs for dynamic FastAPI endpoints?

Tags: python, swagger, fastapi

I have a list of endpoints like below.

```py
endpoints ["/endpoint1", "/endpoint2", "/endpoint3"]
```

I would like to create dynamic endpoints in my app and create swagger API docs for all the endpoints, how can I do this.

```py
@app.route(<endpoint>):
  def process():
```

Comment: In which framework?, [Flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/) or [FastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)  ?

Comment: anything is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**`Enum`**--(FastAPI doc)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/path-params/#create-an-enum-class) classes

```
from enum import Enum
from fastapi import FastAPI


class ModelName(str, Enum):
    endpoint1 = "endpoint1"
    endpoint2 = "endpoint2"
    endpoint3 = "endpoint3"


app = FastAPI()


@app.get("/model/{model_name}")
async def process(model_name: ModelName):
    return {"model_name": model_name, "message": "Some message"}
```

and thus you will get the result as follows,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer, is it possible to provide list of endpoints, instead of hardcoding inside the Class ModelName

Comment: as per my question, I have endpoints in a list... so my use case needs like that

Comment: the term *endpoint* is confusing (me). Is that a [***path parameter***](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/#path-parameters)?

Comment: hmmm yes. I have 5 endpoints and each endpoint have 5 path parameter, in that case, I need 5 `Enum class` I guess. Thanks

Comment: can you provide an example in your answer

Comment: Shouldn't be it handled in a different ***API function***? [ Sorry, I removed the previous comment. ].

Comment: yes different function and different class because the path parameters also differs

Comment: Then, you may need different Enum classes wrt your usecase